# NSubstitute: Why does mock function call returns null when function parameter is byte[]/class?

Tags: parameters, null, return, nsubstitute

I created a Substitute with NSubstitute

```
var mockService = Substitute.For<IService>();
```

I have success in substituting functions from *IService* only if function parameter is **integer**. In other case I receive the result **null/0/byte[0]** when my code calls the functions of *IService*.

```
MyResponse Request(byte[] request, MyAddress target); //null
int test(int t); //expected result
int SimpleRequest(byte[] request, MyAddress target); /0
MyResponse SimpleParam(int i); //expected result
byte[] testbyte(byte[] t); //byte[0]
byte[] testintbyte(int t); //expected result
int testbyteint(byte[] t); //0
```

When I prove this functions in test, they return values as expected:

```
Assert.Equal(mockService.Request(request, target), MyResponse);//true
```

Why can I only use integer as function parameter in NSubstitute?

Comment: You don't show how you are substituting the functions. Maybe post more of your test method. See also https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/set-return-value/ for basics on how to set return values on substitute classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the `byte[]` being passed is a different array. They may have equal values, but be different references.

```cs
var testBytes = new byte[] { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3 };

mockService.testbyteint(testBytes).Returns(42);

Assert.Equal(mockService.testbyteInt(testBytes), 42);
```

This test should pass because the `testBytes` value is pointing to the same reference used for stubbing the call with `Returns`, as well as for the actual call used in the assertion. There are some more examples in the [Return for specific args](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/return-for-args/) documentation.

For cases where we do not have the exact reference required, we can use [argument matchers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/) to define which values we should match:

```cs
var testBytes = new byte[] { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3 };

mockService.testbyteint(Arg.Is<byte[]>(bytes => bytes.SequenceEqual(new[] {0x1, 0x2, 0x3 })).Returns(42);

Assert.Equal(mockService.testbyteInt(testBytes), 42);
```

Another option is when we do not mind which argument we get, we can use [`ReturnsForAnyArgs`](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/return-for-any-args/):

```cs
var testBytes = new byte[] { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3 };

mockService.testbyteint(null).ReturnsForAnyArgs(42);

Assert.Equal(mockService.testbyteInt(testBytes), 42);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: normally SequenceEqual works for byte[], but if I put it in Arg.Is<byte[]>(...) as you suggested I get this error:
`Error CS1929 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'SequenceEqual' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.SequenceEqual<byte>(IQueryable<byte>, IEnumerable<byte>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<byte>' `

Comment: my substitution:  `mockRmqService.testbyteint(
                NSubstitute.Arg.Is<byte[]>(
                    argbytes => argbytes.SequenceEqual<byte>(new[] { 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90 })
                    )).Returns(90);`

Comment: but it works with my real code  `mockRmqService.Request(
                NSubstitute.Arg.Is<byte[]>(argRequest => argRequest.SequenceEqual(ProgramListRequest)).Returns(clientResponse)`! Great!

Comment: @Alexandra Glad you got it working! [`SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.8) availability may depend on the version of .NET you are running. You can also implement your own custom predicate as required.